# The existence of some coordinate cover of a connected manifold whose small shrinking is still a coordinate cover

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a **connected** complex (or differentiable) manifold.

**Question**: **Can we always find a coordinate cover $\{W_k\}$ such that $\{\widetilde{W}_k\}$ is still a coordinate cover of $X$ with $\widetilde{W}_k\subset\subset W_k$？**  (Here $\subset\subset$ means relatively compact)

**Possible clues**: Let $A$ be a **connected** topological space with $A=B \cup C$, where $B$ and $C$ are open subsets of $A$. Then for any fixed point $p\in B\cap C$, there is a small open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, locating  in $B\cap C$. If $U$ contains  more than one point, then it is easy to find proper open subsets $\tilde{B}\subset B$ and $\tilde{C}\subset C$, respectively, such that $A=\tilde{B} \cup \tilde{C}$.

**Another clues**:I suddenly thought of a technique (may call it coordinate ball technique) that seemed to be used on many occasions (But  I can't find the exact source now).

Let $X$ be a (compact) complex manifold. We can cover $X$ by coordinate cover  $\{W_{k}\}$ with every $W_{k}$ biholomorphic  to the ball $B(0,2)$  in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, and $W^{'}_{k}\subset W_k$ is also an open cover with every $W^{'}_{k}$ biholomorphic  to the unit ball $B(0,1)$  in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$.   **Can this
$\{W_{k}\}$  exist?**

Any clues will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you requesting a one to one mapping from the $W_k$ to the $\tilde{W}_k$, i.e. do you want to find exactly one $\tilde{W}^k$ for each $W_k$?

Comment: @Thomas  I want the existence of  $\left\{W_{k}\right\}$ satisfying that there exists its (relative lycompact) shrinking $\bar{W}_{k}$  constituting  a new  coordinate cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, and the cover has only one element $\mathbb{R^n}$. It does not work, since $\mathbb{R^n}$ is not compact.

However, what works is this:

1. $V_k$ locally finite cover with $\overline V_k \subset W_k$,

or

2. $V_i$, with $\overline V_i$ compact, locally finite, and for every $i$ there exists $k=k(i)$ such that $\overline V_i \subset W_{k(i)}$.

So, in general we cannot have both compact closure and the same indexing. However, if $X$ is compact, or $\overline W_k$ are all compact, then from 1. we get $\overline V_k$ compact, so we are OK.

Comment: Thank you.    You are right.  But,  it seems difficult to  ensure   $\bar{V}_{k} \subset W_{k}$.  (the closure is taken in $X$)

Comment: It is a standard result, you can find it for instance in Frank Warner, Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups... the main idea is "compact exhaustion of a manifold"

Comment: Thank you a lot. 
I have reedited the question.  In the ‘’Another clues‘’of
the reedited  question, can this $\left\{W_{k}\right\}$ exist? (P.S.  maybe the answer  for differentiable manifold setting can be found in Warner book)

Comment: @Lelong Wang: Say the $\overline V_k\subset W_k$ can be chosen to be compact ( we saw above some cases when they can). Now, a compact subset of an open ball is contained in a closed ball inside the one ball. So, by enlarging $V_k$ a bit, we can make them diffeo to (smaller ) balls.

Comment: @Lelong Wang: also, in some cases, you want not only the $V_k$, but all possible intersections to be contractible ( for cohomological purposes). In the complex case, you may also want all the possible intersections to be holomorphically convex. It can be done too.